# Plotly: Radar plot mistaking theta as int instead of string

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I am trying to make radar plots, and I want the theta axis to be strings. They should be `["01", "02", "03"]`. However, they are read as numbers by Plotly.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    r=[22, 6, 0],
    theta=["01", "02", "03"]))
fig = px.line_polar(df, r='r', theta='theta', line_close=True)
fig.update_traces(fill='toself')
fig.show()
```

[image]

However, if I add some text to the array, it is read as a string and I obtain the figure I'm looking for.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(r=[22, 6, 0],
                       theta=["Code: 01", "Code: 02", "Code: 03"]))
fig = px.line_polar(df, r='r', theta='theta', line_close=True)
fig.update_traces(fill='toself')
fig.show()
```

[image]

How can I make Plotly read the array as a string without having to add extra text? (the actual plot is much more crowded).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what's happening here is that the `type` of the angular axis is being inferred to be `linear` instead of `category` because all the strings contain only numbers. If you add a non-numeric string this coaxes the inference the other way.

You can explicitly set the type for both the `plotly.express` and `plotly.graph_objects` approach with

```py
fig.update_polars(angularaxis_type="category") # chaining-friendly
```

or

```py
fig.layout.polar.angularaxis.type="category" # more imperative style
```

Answer (score 0):

If you won't mind a little html formatting, any html formatting seems to force plotly to interpret your input as text.

**Plot:**

[image]

As you can see I've used italics `<i>yourtext</i>` but any html should work. In fact, the [span](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) tag will leave your text unformatted.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(r=[22, 6, 0], theta=['01','02','03']))

df['thetaText'] = ['<i>'+elem+'</i>' for elem in df['theta']]

fig = px.line_polar(df, r='r', theta='thetaText', line_close=True)
fig.update_traces(fill='toself')
fig.show()
```

**Edit:**

If you'd like to use `[1,2,3]` as input for theta instead, just change 
`df['thetaText'] = ['<i>'+elem+'</i>' for elem in df['theta']]` to `df['thetaText'] = ['<i>'+str(elem)+'</i>' for elem in df['theta']]`

Comment: Instead of italics (or wrapping the number in a useless `<span>`, does prepending the number with a zero-width non-breaking space (`&#xfeff;`) perchance work?

Comment: @kthy I didn't test it. Do you think it would be less laborious than `'<span>'+elem+'</span>'`?